# Cant connect ubuntu terminal and python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, subprocess

Im trying to use ubuntu terminal through python script.

The script receives the command text(from input() for test), sends it to the terminal, the terminal return the result of the command, script print result in a console.

I already get that I should use subprocess Popen and PIPE, but after inputing 1st command, script print only b'', after 2nd raise error "ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication"

my test code(yes, its bad):

```
import subprocess as sb
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

p=Popen(['gnome-terminal'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)

command = 'cmd'
while True:
    command = input()
    out_data, err_data = p.communicate(command.encode())
    print(repr(out_data))
```

I know I do it in a wrong way, but can't find right. Sorry for English.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the os module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
output = os.listdir('path_to_folder')  # output is a list
# Do whatever you want to output
```

You can read more about what else the os module can do at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html. Note that the methods in the module are portable across different OSes, so you can in fact use your script outside Ubuntu.